# What role to give a sql login in order to create a database and additional logins

Tags: sql-server-2005

What role should I give a sql login if I need the login to be able to create a database, and create additional logins and add users based on those logins to the database i created?  This is sql 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fixed database role that includes these permissions.  You'll have to create a role and assign the permissions individually.

```
CREATE ROLE db_creator
GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO db_creator
GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN TO db_creator
GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO db_creator
```